# While working with internationalization in spring boot, why messages.getmessage() returns null?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

the result when examining messages.gettmessage() is null using the model.addAttribute to get the message to display it on thymeleaf page.

I have a registrationConfirm Controller to allow users to confirm their emails

Here is my Registration Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/registrationConfirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String confirmRegistration(final HttpServletRequest request, final 
 Model model, @RequestParam("token") final String token) throws 
 UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Locale locale = request.getLocale();

    final String result = userService.validateConfirmationToken(token);
    if (result.equals("valid")) {
        final User user = userService.getUser(token);
        authWithoutPassword(user);
        model.addAttribute("message", 
        messages.getMessage("message.accountVerified", null, locale));
        return "redirect:/home.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();
    }

    model.addAttribute("message", messages.getMessage("auth.message." + 
     result, null, locale));
    model.addAttribute("expired", "expired".equals(result));
    model.addAttribute("token", token);
    return "redirect:/wrong.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();
    }
```

My MvcConfig Class:

```
    @Configuration
    public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
          super.addViewControllers(registry);
          registry.addViewController("/index");
          registry.addViewController("/registration");
          registry.addViewController("/wrong.html");
            registry.addViewController("/home.html");
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final 
    DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        final CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new 
        CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }      
   @Bean
   public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
       LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
       lci.setParamName("lang");
       return lci;
   }
   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
       registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
   }
```

Note that when trying to confirm the email with an invalid token that will redirect to badUser.html which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title th:text="#{label.wrong.title}">wrong</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="alert alert-info" th:text="${param.message[0]}">error</div> 
<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get the param.message and get the error below in logs

Request processing failed; nested exception is

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating 
SpringEL expression: "param.message[0]" (wrong)
Root Cause: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value
```

Sorry for the long code, I was trying to fix this issue for long time. ANY HELP IS REALLY APPRECIATED!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your `message` variable is a view model, you shouldn't use the `param.` prefix for it in the html (Thymeleaf view). From thymeleaf documentation:

> **param** : for retrieving request parameters. `${param.foo}` is a `String[]` with the values of the `foo` request parameter, so `${param.foo[0]}` will normally be used for getting the first value.

So, in the end just use `message`.

**UPDATE**

You should also avoid redirection, since your `message` variable will be lost as soon as you redirect. In addition to that, you should redirect to the controller itself.

Replace the line:

```
return "redirect:/home.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();
```

With:

```
if (request.getParameterMap().size() == 0)
    return "redirect:/registrationConfirm?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();
// ...
return "home";
```

However, for efficiency move the `if` block in the above code to the first line of your `registrationConfirm()` method body.

I tested this with spring-boot 1.5.6 and Spring MVC 4.3

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Leone, but when using message[0] instead of param.message[0] I am getting the same error

Comment: My update on this: When adding the @EnableWebMvc annotation in the MvcConfig.java it is running and I can see the messages in thymeleaf correctly. But I dont want to add this annotation because of using spring boot

Comment: thanks for your replies but it unfortunately it doesnt work for me that way. it redirects me to registrationConfirm.html but same error. Maybe there is something wrong with my configurations or beans?

Comment: Are you still getting `Cannot index into a null value` error? And have you restarted your app?

Comment: And one more thing is that you should do the redirects (like in the answer above) for both `return "redirect:/home.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();` part and the one below it: `return "redirect:/wrong.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();`

Comment: change it as all as you suggest, it redirects to registrationConfirm and still getting same error and cannot index into a null value error

Comment: Can you debug and look at what the value of `messages.getMessage("auth.message." + 
     result, null, locale)` is? Because if it is returning `null` then the error is legit.

Comment: NO it is not null @Leone I am sorry,

Comment: Are you sure you are still getting **`Cannot index into a null value`** error?

Comment: I am still getting as I mentioned earlier, org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "message[0]" (wrong)
Root Cause: rg.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value